# Rewrite an URL without 302 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I would like to know, how can i rewrite an URL without the 302 redirection.
The website is targeted by 2 domains.

- The first domains `(domain1.com)` focus **all the website**.
- The second domains `(domain2.com)` focus only one function to do an **url shortener**

Here is my `.htaccess` :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ http://domain2.com/url/$1 [L]

Rewritecond %{HTTP_HOST} domain2.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://domain2.com/soon/ [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

When i call my shothener `http://domain2.com/57b97f2` i'am redirect to `http://domain2.com/url/57b97f2` with a 302 redirection.

How can i avoid this unwanted 302 redirection ?

======= EDIT ======= :

My controller for the `url()` function is named : `webadmin`

My routes are :

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'webadmin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['(.+)'] = 'webadmin/$1';
```

Webadmin controller :

```
function url($code)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: You must remove `http://domain2.com` from your rules (otherwise you get a redirect, even with `L` flag). But both `domain1` and `domain2` must share the same document root folder to make it work this way

Comment: Domain1 and Domain2 focus the same document root actually.

Comment: Ok first good point. Now, what do you want instead of a 302 redirect ? Also, is `url/57b97f2` (for instance) a real file/folder ?

Comment: When i call my shorten url, i would like my function `url()` be called without redirect to `domain2.com/url/57b97f2` but to `domain2.com/57b97f2`

Comment: Well simply remove `http://domain2.com` from your rule: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ /url/$1 [L]` . This means if you go now to `http://domain2.com/something` it will internally rewrite to `/url/something` (you'll then have to handle it there)

Comment: I already try this but i redirected to **404 Page Not Found**, maybe the codeIngiter routes are for something ?

Comment: I don't know. What do you have at `/url/XXX` ? Do you handle it somewhere ? What do you expect to have ?

Comment: what exactly is this rule suposed to do except for sending that 302 redirect -> `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ http://domain2.com/url/$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

# 1. If we're on the root of domain2.com, temporarilty redirect to
#    the `/soon` handler
#    Note: This redirect should really be temporary, as it is a
#          landing page for your soon-to-be-released app/site.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /soon [R=302,L]

# 2. If we're on domain2.com, rewrite short URIs to the `/url` handler
#    Note the use of the `N` flag which causes the ruleset to start
#    again from the beginning using the result of the rewrite. This
#    will cause the rewritten URI to be passed to `index.php` (the
#    last RewriteRule).
#    Also added is the NC flag, which may or may not be better than
#    specifying `A-Z` in the pattern's expression.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain2\.com$
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)$ /url/$1 [NC,N]

# 3. Redirect application/system directory requests to index.php

RewriteRule ^(application|system) /index.php?/$1 [L]

# 4. For everything else (sans files and directories), rewrite to index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Note that I have simplified much of your code.

Also, I haven't tested this, but it should work (theoretically).

Comment: Thank's for the simplified code but i still have the `404 Page Not Found`. When i go to http://www.domain2.com/codeurl

Comment: Please see my update - I have changed the second block to explicitly rewrite to `index.php?/url/$1`.

Comment: I have edit my aswer with more informations, i still have the 404 error with your update :/

Comment: With your update i need to add `/url/code` to make it work else i have a 404

Comment: I apologise, but my update was indeed flawed (rolled my answer back). That said, it may be better to handle this inside CI itself, and not in`.htaccess`.

Comment: Could you please give me some few clues about the way to build my route into Codeingiter ?

Comment: I'm not a CI user, but you could try this in your routes file (above the last rule you have there): `$route['url/(:any)'] = 'webmadmin/url/$1';` If it works for you, I'll add it as an answer. Also be sure to use the **current** `.htaccess` code in my answer.

Comment: On the config.php i have change : `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` -> `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and now it work. But i don't know why... Can you explain me ? And you can add this to your answer.

Comment: Ah, of course. In the `htaccess` file, you are rewriting to `index.php?/$1`. See the question mark? That means you are rewriting to the `QUERY_STRING`, and so you have to tell CI to check that. If you want to use the `REQUEST_URI`, then you would need to remove the question mark from the rule.